# How to split() strings based on a delimiter?

Tags: javascript

I would like to convert a String into an Array.
My string looks like this:

> First-Second-Third-Fourth-Fifth-Sixth

and my Array should look like this:

> ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"]

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: *Is there any way to do that?* No, unless you have a computing device which is [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can split the string:

```
var myArray = myString.split('-');
```